# Run anonymous function on current & future elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to run an anonymous function on specified future elements once they become part of the DOM.  I couldn't find an answer to this.  I need a cross-browser event that bubbles, and only runs once when the element is created, or ready, or something along those lines.

Internet Explorer has the "activate" event which is just what I need, except it is only in IE.  I tried using the DOMActivate event in Chrome, but it behaves strangely when I tested it on a text input box.  It would only fire when the element is clicked on, and it fired twice in a row.  It acted like a focus event that is triggered twice, which is not helpful.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
            $('body').on('activate', '.date-picker', function () {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                });
            });

            $('body').on('DOMActivate', '.date-picker', function () {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                });
            });
```

I realize I can accomplish this with future elements using a callback after I place them on the DOM, or by triggering my own event, but I was looking for a cleaner solution.

EDIT:

I got it to work like this:

```
            $('body').on('activate', '.date-picker', function (e) {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                });
            });
            var activateSupported = 'onactivate' in document.documentElement;
            if (!activateSupported) {
                $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
                    var target = $(e.target);
                    target.trigger('activate');
                    target.find('*').trigger('activate');
                });
            }
```

This isn't really ideal as it has to make all those extra function calls in browsers other than IE.  Anyone have better solutions?

Comment: I'm trying to do it globally and generically so I don't need custom code to specifically handle the situations where elements are added to the page later.

Comment: Can still use it on the Body. I have added a answer with an example, just replacing `DOMActivate` with `DOMSubtreeModified`

Comment: Personally, the call to 'init' the datepicker would be best suited in in the code that adds it ( like you say, in the callback or something )

Comment: That's what I am currently doing, I just thought I could save some code by having all the datepicker events be bound in one place.

Comment: I understand that I can do that, but I wanted a solution that datepickers would always work without having to bind it manually in cases where future elements are placed on the page.

Comment: What type of datepicker are you creating? an input that pops up a datepicker on focus? There is an easy cross-browser solution that scenario in an existing answer here on SO, if that's what you're looking for i'll link it.

Comment: Ya, I'm just using jQuery's date picker.

Comment: I know that... are you using it on an input, or a div.

Comment: I'm using it on an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how this plugin works (it is not visible until you focus the input,) you can lazy-bind the plugin using event delegation.

```
$(document).on("focus", ".date-picker", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass(".date-picker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'}).focus();
});
```

The first time it is focused, it is initialized. After it is initialized, the focus event is re-triggered to cause the datepicker to open. By removing the `.date-picker` class, I prevent it from re-initializing the datepicker on subsequent focus events.

Comment: This seems to work well.  It's too bad using .one doesn't work as it doesn't fire once per element in this case:

                $(document).one('focus', '.date-picker', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' }).focus();
                });

Comment: Right, i dislike that about .one too. The logic there is it fires once per *selected* element, the selected element being `$(document)`